# IndexError: too many indices for array using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have trouble in solving this problem. I am using python numpy. And my goal is to print traffic light countdown.

EDIT:  So it's like in 1 intersection, there are 8 stoplights, and 3 timings(red,amber,green). But my plus intersection consists of 4 intersection.

8 stoplights mean
straight road, north to south
straight road, south to north
straight road, east to west
straight road, west to east

left turn, north to west
left turn, west to north
left turn, north to east
left turn, east to south

```
//edited
t = np.zeros((4, 8, 3)) //4 intersections, 8 stoplights, 3 timings

 for i in range(8):
   for j in range(4):
       t[j,i,0] = 10
       t[j,i,1] = 5
       t[j,i,2] = 10
```

In the code stated above, it would give an error  "Too many indices in array"

```
t[j,i,0] = 10
t[j,i,1] = 5
t[j,i,2] = 10
```

Can somebody please tell me why and how to solve this.

Comment: What is  the last block of formatted code for?

Comment: I think it may just be you access like this: `t[0] = 4`, `t[1] = 8`, `t[2]=3` So it should only take 1 index for its place in the array.

Comment: You just created 1D array but you are probably trying to create 3D array.

Comment: What are you trying to do in ` t[j,i,0]`

Comment: @ShivamJha j and i there are 4(for intersections) and 8(for stoplights)

Comment: Yes @sanitizedUser. I'm sorry it should be t = np.zeros((4,8,4)) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a 3 dimensional array, probably you should be doing:

```
t = np.zeros((4,8,3))
```

You are actually creating a single dimensional array of elements 4,8,3